# Error displaying a div until it reaches the page's bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm displaying a div in front of another div, to display a loading div with an observable; the thing is that when the loading div is displayed it grows and an "ugly scroll bar" appears, is it possible to only display the loading div until it reach the page's bottom.

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Hello loading div</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <button data-bind= "click: startLoading">Start loading</button>
        <button data-bind= "click: stopLoading">Stop loading</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <!-- ko if: tabLoading -->
          <div class="tab-loading-mask" id="tab-loading-mask-edit"></div>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

My code example is here: https://codepen.io/the-writer/pen/NXNLob, I'm not adding the knockout js tag because I'm only using the observable of this library.

Comment: Are you talking about simply removing the horizontal scrollbar from the grey overlay, or are you looking to change the behaviour of the vertical scrollbar as well?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough but I'm refering to the vertical scroll bar. . .

Answer (score 1):

Since `.tab-loading-mask` is `position: absolute;` its parent needs `position: relative;`

`position: absolute;` elements are positioned relative to their nearest positioned parent

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.tabLoading = ko.observable(false);
    this.startLoading = () => {
      this.tabLoading(true);
      console.log("Start");
    }
    
    this.stopLoading = () => {
      this.tabLoading(false);
      console.log("Stoped");
    }
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
.nav-bar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}


.tab-loading-mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Hello loading div</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <button data-bind= "click: startLoading">Start loading</button>
        <button data-bind= "click: stopLoading">Stop loading</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <!-- ko if: tabLoading -->
          <div class="tab-loading-mask" id="tab-loading-mask-edit"></div>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I loaded your code but I still see a problem, the tab-loading-mask is not growing to the bottom of the page. Right now it only fit the div.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scrollbar appears because of the combination of **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)** on `.tab-loading-mask` and the inherent **[`margin: 8px`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** on `<body>`. Setting `position: absolute` takes the element out of the flow, so when you set `width: 100%` on `.tab-loading-mask`, it takes up `100%` of the width **regardless** of the margins that are in play.

To remedy this, you have two options:

1) Override the default `margin` on body back to `0`. This will make all elements on the page flush right up against the edge of the page, which may not be intentional (your `.nav-bar` is offset, for example):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
  this.tabLoading = ko.observable(false);
  this.startLoading = () => {
    this.tabLoading(true);
    //console.log("Start");
  }

  this.stopLoading = () => {
    this.tabLoading(false);
    //console.log("Stoped");
  }
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.tab-loading-mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <button data-bind="click: startLoading">Start loading</button>
      <button data-bind="click: stopLoading">Stop loading</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- ko if: tabLoading -->
        <div class="tab-loading-mask" id="tab-loading-mask-edit"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

2) Make use of **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** to set a `width` of `100% - (8px * 2)` on `.tab-loading-mask`. This accommodates for the `8px` of margin on either side of the element, causing it to be flush with `.nav-bar`'s offset.

```
.tab-loading-mask {
  width: calc(100% - (8px * 2));
}
```

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
  this.tabLoading = ko.observable(false);
  this.startLoading = () => {
    this.tabLoading(true);
    //console.log("Start");
  }

  this.stopLoading = () => {
    this.tabLoading(false);
    //console.log("Stoped");
  }
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
.nav-bar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.tab-loading-mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - (8px * 2));
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <button data-bind="click: startLoading">Start loading</button>
      <button data-bind="click: stopLoading">Stop loading</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- ko if: tabLoading -->
        <div class="tab-loading-mask" id="tab-loading-mask-edit"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note the difference in the whitespace around the two snippets.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, buit this is not what I'm looking for I want that  the tab-loading-mask grows to the bottom of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are actually asking how to fill 2 elements in the viewport in a column, one with a fixed height, and the other will fill up the remaining height,

You could use `display: flex;` set to column to display the 2 divs vertically within the height of the viewport

Removing the margin, and set everything to border-box for a more uniform styling, or better yet, use a css reset like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-bar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="nav-bar">NAV BAR</div>

  <div class="content">

    <div class="tab-content">CONTENT</div>

  </div>

</div>
```